# Cant find the image links to images on the website in html I bought. I own it, but where is it?

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, hidden

I can't find the link in the html to 3 images on the front page of my website. The black spy on green background and the two black graphs on green background. The website is here : home.alphaphoner.com it's a template I bought online, but now I want to update it and I can't. Can anyone find the links?

Comment: why am I getting minus for this question? Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's because they aren't actually images, so you can't link to or download them as they require HTML, CSS and a font to display.
They are part of the "FontAwesome" library which uses a font to store the icons, and uses CSS to style them.

The "spy" icon is here: https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=incognito

Comment: PHEW thanks a lot, that would have taken me forever to find out.